# Testing algorithm against large dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing, rspec, statistics

I'm implementing a statistical algorithm that needs access to a large sample dataset for proper testing.  Large being 50,000 rows in a single table, MySQL.

I would like to use traditional RSpec methods to test, but creating the sample set and loading it into the DB leads to two problems.

- Extremely slow/intensive using Active Record create.  I haven't explored various options to create to skip validation, since the models are pretty basic and I assume it won't make a huge speed difference
- Improper cleanup using a hacky `mysqlimport` (meaning data left in the database after test, despite an explicit call to DatabaseCleaner in an :after block)

Creating the object graph in-memory is a possibility, but not being a mockist I'm a little afraid to override AR functionality.

Any ideas, best practices?

Thanks!
Justin

Comment: Is the sample set readonly? I.e. can you use the same values in the table for all the examples?

Comment: Even by MySQL standards, 50k rows is tiny. Think of gigabyte/petabyte as good markers to distinguish tiny, small and large databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a partial answer, but:

> - Extremely slow/intensive using Active Record create. (...) I assume it won't make a huge speed difference

It actually is a big speed difference. PostgreSQL has a good guide on this:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/populate.html

Most it applies to MySQL directly:

- Use a single transaction, rather than many of them.
- Load data in file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html
- Remove indexes and recreate them after the inserts.
- Disable fkey constraints while loading your data (assumes your data is clean, of course).
- Give MySQL plenty of resources.
- Disable replication if applicable.

> - Improper cleanup using a hacky mysqlimport (meaning data left in the database after test, despite an explicit call to DatabaseCleaner in an :after block)

If you want to flush your tables of all their data, try truncate:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: There's also a larger memory footprint for an instantiated AR object than for the corresponding line in an SQL file that would populate the database.